# How to pop up new window using pyqt, qt designer

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, qt-designer

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import uic

MainWindow = uic.loadUiType("simulator_ver_0.1.ui")[0]
AddFuseWindow = uic.loadUiType("simulator_add_fuse_ver_0.1.ui")[0]
AddLoadWindow = uic.loadUiType("simulator_add_load_ver_0.1.ui")[0]

class MyWindow2(QWidget, AddFuseWindow):
    def _init_():
        super()._init_(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

class MyWindow3(QWidget , AddLoadWindow):
    def _init_():
        super()._init_(self)
        self.setupUi(self)


class MyWindow(QMainWindow, MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connect(self.actionFuse, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.add_fuse)
        self.connect(self.actionLoad, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.add_load)


    def add_fuse(self):
        self.w2 = MyWindow2(self)
        self.w2.show()

    def add_load(self):
        self.w3=MyWindow3()
        self.w3.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = MyWindow()
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

here is my python code.
I loaded three ui files from qt designer.
I already created MyWindow class, which is MainWindow. I want to pop up MyWindow2 or MyWindow3, When I click the toolbar. It was successful to pop up new window , but it was not what I created. It was just empty window.
It seems like python didn't load AddFuseWindow and AddLoadWindow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR0fu.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the new pop up window in a funtion and connect it to the toolbar item.

```
self.toolbaritem.triggered.connect(self.doSomething)

def doSomething(self):
    window = OtherWindow()
    window.show()
    self.close()


class OtherWindow():
    def dothis(self):
        window = SampleWin()
        window.show()
        self.close()
```

you can also use [QStackedWidget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstackedwidget.html) to do the same thing.